# How to navigate through a directory?

Tags: php, html, directory

I am creating a website with a simple file manager whose task is simply to open folders and search for pdf files in them. I have a "dir" root folder, and it contains other folders and files that users will work with.
Let's say the folder "dir" contains the folder "books", and in it the folders "history", "physics", "math" and so on. I can easily go to the "history" folder, but from "history" to let's say "history for kids" I can't go (I understand, it's very easy to get confused, but I tell it like it is). I looked at how I navigate through the directory and saw the following

What I should have seen:
1.dir
2.dir/history
3.dir/history/history for kids

What I saw:
1.dir
2.dir/history
3.dir/history for kids

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'dir';
    if (isset($_POST['btn-act'])) {
        $folder .= '/'.$_POST['btn-act'];
    }
    echo $folder;
    if (is_dir($folder)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($folder)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($file !='.' && $file !='..') {
                    if (is_dir($folder.'/'.$file)) {
                        echo "<li><form method='post'><img src='img/folder.png' class='folder'> <input type='submit' name='btn-act' value='$file'></form></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li> <img src='img/pdf.png' class='folder'> " . $file . " " . filesize($folder.'/'.$file) ."</li>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `readdir` returns the file _name_ only. You will have to add the path prefix to the value you are submitting via your form. (Why a form and method=post to begin with? _Links_ are for navigating.)